# How many rows of data in a text file

Tags: powerbuilder

I'm new to Powerbuilder and here I have some question about how to find how many rows/lines of data there is in a text file. First I tried a approach of FileLength but could not figure how to to do that with my current logic. Could not find any example of how to do it with it either so here I am wanting some help!

What I'm doing is generating a password from a txt file.

Notes:
gsa_wordlist is a global variable.

Also if you as experienced developer see any common pitfalls then please do tell.

My code on Click():

```
int li_rand
int li_upperboundList
int li_FileNum
string ls_fileurl
string ls_listout
int i
li_upperboundList = Upperbound(gsa_wordlist)
ls_fileurl = 'C:\Users\abg\Documents\wordlist.txt'

IF li_upperboundList < 100 THEN
Beep(1)

li_FileNum = FileOpen(ls_fileurl)
FOR i = 1 TO // TO HOW MANY LINES OF DATA
    FileReadEx(li_FileNum, ls_listout)
    gsa_wordlist[i] = ls_listout
NEXT

li_upperboundList = Upperbound(gsa_wordlist)
li_rand = rand(li_upperboundList)
sle_genpass.Text = string(li_rand)
ELSE
    Beep(2)
    li_rand = rand(li_upperboundList)
    sle_genpass.Text = gsa_wordlist[li_rand]
END IF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to know how many rows, just loop until EOF.

```
li_FileNum=FileOpen(ls_fileurl,LineMode!,Read!,LockRead!)

i = 1

DO While FileReadEx(li_FileNum,ls_listout) <> -100
   gsa_wordlist[i++] = ls_listout
LOOP
FileClose(li_FileNum)
```

PS. Add a check inside the loop for the `li_upperboundList` limit !

Comment: Why this line `1=1`?

Comment: Not `1=1`, it's  `i=1`

Comment: Ho, sorry, I 'll have to change glasses.  By the way this show how easily a problem can be overseen, even rereading the same code a thousand times.

Answer (score 0):

Can you think of any reason not to use a datastore?

It would be easy to import the words into a datastore and then you would have search, sort, insert, delete methods immediately available. ImportFile is also much faster than ReadFile.

To start, create a datawindow with external data source named d_dictionary with a column that can accommodate your data.

Then declare global variable

```
datastore gds_dictionary
```

Example code

```
long ll_rows
string ls_fileurl = 'C:\Users\abg\Documents\wordlist.txt'

if not isvalid( gds_dictionary ) then
    gds_dictionary = create datastore
    gds_dictionary.dataobject = "d_dictionary"
end if

gds_dictionary.reset( )
ll_rows = gds_dictionary.ImportFile( ls_fileurl )

if ll_rows < 1 then
   //oops! Something bad happened
else
   gds_dictionary.sort( )
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Generating password from a text file that way is pretty bad idea. in fact you rely on characters when generating password and never pick complete words from a file. A file with many words in it is used when you re recovering a forgotten password. Also the word that make sense or have meaning if used as password is sure a weak password.

If you get a chance to see control panel of some Web hosting service Providers then you might find a good example of a generated strong password there(Not all web hosting providers provide that).

But it is very easy to make a program that does the same thing. for example following PowerBuilder Script do the trick.

```
Integer MaxLength = 10, TheNextCode
Integer ASCII_Range[33 TO 125]
String ThePass
DO While  Len(ThePass) < MaxLength
    TheNextCode = Rand(125) 
    IF TheNextCode < 33 THEN Continue
   ThePass += String(Char(TheNextCode))
LOOP
mle.Text += ThePass + "~r~n"
```